# Adjusting ROR snippet to show updated images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Since I'm rather new to rails I need some advise.

I have this code snipped (below) that is supposed to show the first image of the latest created product in my app.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
        <div class="row">
          <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>

                <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                    <% if index == 0 %>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                        <%= link_to category_path (category), { :method => 'GET' } do %>
                            <% if product.images.first %>
                 <%= image_tag product.images.first.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
               <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                <div class="caption">
                <p class="category-name" ><%= product.category.name %></p>
                 </div> 
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div> 
            <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

</div>
```

Now I'm in the process at updating images for the products.  I would like to have the newly added images shown on the index page.

As the code works now, It only adds new images to the `index` page if I create a new product.

How can I adjust this code to show updated products ( the newly added image to the product)?

Comment: Most likely it's because you have `product.images.first.image.url(:medium)` in your image_tag. So you are always see `.first` image. Try changing `.first` to `.last` and see what happens.

Comment: so you want only latest images first?

Comment: Yes basically, the latest uploaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the updated_at field of parent object Product whenever image changes

> belongs_to :product, touch: true

2. Fetch the products order by updated_at

> @products = Product.order(:updated_by=>:desc)

Comment: It works, thank you... I also changed the `.first` to `.last` so maybe that is changing things.